# Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined - Magento 2.3

Tags: jquery, magento, fancybox-3

I'm trying to get fancybox to work in Magento 2.3 (with Infortis Ultimo Theme).

But I'm getting:

```
1. Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined 
2. Uncaught TypeError: fancyboxExample.init is not a function
```

I'm trying to use the following solution:

https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/158894/jquery-fancybox-for-magento-2

**Error**

[image]

I load the following through `default_head_blocks.xml` using `<link src="js/custom.js"/>`.

```
require(['jquery', 'fancybox', 'domReady!'], function($, fancybox, doc) {
var fancyboxExample = {
    openModal: function() {
        $.fancybox.open(this.$modal);
    },
    closeModal: function() {
        $.fancybox.close(true);
    }
};
fancyboxExample.init();
});
```

Anyone who can shed some light on this?
Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Require JS config should be

```
File: app/design/frontend/Store/theme/requirejs-config.js

  var config = {
    map: {
      '*': {
        fancybox: 'js/vendor/fancybox3/jquery.fancybox.min'
         }
     },
    shim: {
            'fancybox': {
                deps: ['jquery']
            }
        }
 };
```

Comment: If you are using custom js then you should use define instead of require